# background image vertical repeat for a div

Tags: css

I want to repeat a background-image for a div vertically till the bottom of the page.

```
#repeat {
   background: url(repeat-image.png) repeat-y;
   height: 100%; /* this does not work, but height: 1024px; does */
}
```

This does not work. I need to do so according to the page design that I have got. Can this be done?

With regards
Vikram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set `height:100%` for your `<body>` and `<html>`, too. if there is nothing except this div on your page, 100% height will be 0px without these settings.

Comment: I hadn't tried to set the height on html, that's why it wasn't working I guess. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

For web pages, height is a funny thing. Since web pages expand vertically, the total height of your page can actually be 0. You may consider using min-height for each element that requires at least a certain height. You can use height: 100% to fill the full height of the parent.