# Repeat Image past set div?

Tags: css, image, html

Is there a way to make an image repeat beyond the element div that it is placed in? When the browser is maximized, the picture will stop where the footer stops but I'd like to repeat to the max height of the browser. Possible without putting the image in the body bg? I can't place it in the body bg because of a jquery animation, and IE gradient code and an image can't be put together. Thanks.

-edit- found the solution

[background image vertical repeat for a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004066/background-image-vertical-repeat-for-a-div)

set the html and body in css with `height:100%;`

and also `height:100%;` in the div with image

worked because the div with the image was the first div before the reset of the content div

Comment: An easy solution to "short footers" is to put the content and header in containers but the footer will just be the body color.

Comment: I see, it works in firefox, however, now the animation I put doesn't show up in IE... sigh

Comment: found the issue didn't put a space after the bg url and repeat;... sigh

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have images repeat outside of the parent div size in such a way that is still cross-browser compatible as far as I know.